# Как управлять задержкой вызова dispatchKeyEvent() при зажатой кнопке android?

Tags: android, kotlin

Все перерыл, нигде не найду ответ( Есть приложение для android tv. В списке каналов при быстрой прокрутке (при долго зажатой кнопке keycode_dpad_down или keycode_dpad_up) приложение начинает тормозить и если совсем долго держать то просто зависает, потом отвисает и встает на какой-то канал. Как я понимаю происходит это потому, что нажатие кнопки обрабатывается в методе dispatchKeyEvent и при зажатой кнопке этот метод вызывается раз 10-12 за секунду, экран просто не успевает перерисоваться(там еще и анимация есть, с плавным перемещением списка каналов), сначала начинает тормозить а потом, когда количество вызовов метода начинает превышать все разумные пределы, просто зависает. Вопрос, как ограничить вызов этого метода 2-3 в секунду например или может есть какой то другой выход из положения? При однократном нажатии все разумеется работает хорошо. Задача, чтобы список прокручивался плавно вверх-вниз с зажатой кнопкой... Помогите, плиз, кто сталкивался, или хоть намекните) Заранее благодарю)

Comment: Вроде сам придумал только что. Можно создать флаг и на key_down ставить его в true, запускать бесконечный цикл переключения каналов с паузой например в 500мс, пока не false а на key_up ставить его в false. Мб и сработает, завтра на работе погляжу)

Comment: Не работает этот способ, при долгом зажатии клавиши метод onKeyDown точно так же вызывается раз 10-12 за секунду(

Comment: Можно запоминать время последней обработки в переменную. В `onKeyDown` сравнивать её с текущим временем: если прошло 500мс - переключаем канал и обновляем переменную, если нет - ничего не делаем.

Comment: Проблема в том, что сам метод onKeyDown вызываться то все равно будет десятки раз. Я предполагал, что метод onKeyDown вызывается один раз при нажатии кнопки и ее задержке в нажатом состоянии и потом при отпускании её срабатывает метод onKeyUp, но метод onKeyDown срабатывает очень много раз и даже если какую то логику внутри него добавлять он все равно будет вызываться кучу раз и будет все тормозить(

Comment: Если в одном вызове вы будете делать полезную работу, а в 20-ти (условно) только поверять прошло ли время - то ничего тормозить не будет, другие приложения ведь работают нормально и в тех же условиях. Ограничить количество самих вызовов вы не можете - для этого нужно модифицировать саму систему, или пульт и возможно паяльником - вряд ли юзерам это понравится)). Могу написать пример на java, если хотите, на котлине не могу

Comment: Буду очень вам признателен, уже голову сломал и весь инет перерыл))

Answer (score 0):

Можно запоминать время последней обработки (пример на `java`):

```
// объявляем поле класса, в котором будем хранить тайм-штамп
private long lastActionTime;

public abstract boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    long currentTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    if (currentTime - lastActionTime < 500) {
        // 500мс ещё не прошло - выходим
        return;
    }
    lastActionTime = currentTime;

    // здесь делаем что нужно
}
```

Если нужно таким же образом обрабатывать одновременные нажатия нескольких кнопок, то тайм-штампы придётся хранить в отдельной переменной для каждой кнопки, либо массиве или коллекции.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, буду пробовать